# Redirecting port 80 to another port on a single Windows computer?

Tags: windows, networking, proxy, port-forwarding, transparent-proxy

Assuming my Windows (xp, vista, 2003, 2008, or windows 7) computer is connected directly to the internet and has no router in between...

Is there a way to filter all traffic going TO port 80, so that it instead goes to 3128 (squid HTTP proxy)?

I found [this port mapping software](http://www.softperfect.com/products/bandwidth/), but you need another computer because it can't redirect outgoing requests.

Comment: Even if not native, please let me know a program that can do it instead

Comment: There's this really sweet program called Linux that would fix this in a heartbeat. ;)

Comment: In this network arrangement, where does the proxy server live? Is the Windows machine the web server or client? BTW, there is always a router between you and the "Internet". Just as Soilent Green is made of people, the Internet is made of routers.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this can be done natively in windows. Why don't you just set Squid to listen on port 80?

Comment: Because I want to transparently router all web page traffic through squid.  I don't think setting squid to listen on port 80 has anything to do that.  Am I maybe missing something in the understanding of squid?

Answer (score 1):

The product you are looking for is [NetCat](http://www.securityfocus.com/tools/139) and does exactly what you need. Check the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat) page. The specific command line you want is

nc -l -p 80 | nc localhost 3128

Comment: This allows me to receive any traffic on port 80 (incoming).  What I need to do is redirect any outgoing traffic on port to go to 127.0.0.1 3128.

Answer (score 1):

This article from Microsoft ( http://support.microsoft.com/kb/819961 ) discusses configuring a proxyserver for the system. For other browsers, such as firefox, you may need to configure the proxy settings independently.

Comment: I need to do this in a transparent way

Answer (score 1):

I recognize this doesn't answer your question, but you should really put a real firewall/router appliance in place to do this: I would recommend either [pfSens](http://pfsense.org/)e or [Smoothwall](http://www.smoothwall.org/).

If it has to be a Windows box for whatever reason, your best bet is [ISA Server](http://www.microsoft.com/forefront/edgesecurity/isaserver/en/us/product-information.aspx) - though typically it handles in-bound routing better so this may not even be possible. As far as I know, Microsoft has not exposed the IP stack in such a way you can add custom routes/translations without writing a custom driver to sit in the network stack.

Excellent ISA resource: http://www.isaserver.org/

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Linux, the best way to do this would be iptables.

Make sure ip_forward is on

```
echo 1 >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Replace IP_ADDRESS with your destination IP address

> iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination IP_ADDRESS
>
> iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d IP_ADDRESS --dport 80 -j MASQUERADE

I use it regularly to redirect all traffic from one server to another server, usually after a server migration into another datacenter.

Answer (score 1):

The shareware PC Port Forwarding is all there is for redirecting outgoing traffic with an easy to use GUI under Windows.  Obtain it from http://www.verigio.com/products/pc-port-forwarding/

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You **can** do what you're looking for with [SoftPerfect Bandwidth Manager and Squid](http://www.softperfect.com/support/articles/squid/) on a single server.

If you can't handle the cost of SoftPerfect Bandwidth Manager you'd probably do well to get any one of the "canned" Linux distributions that come with Squid pre-installed and just use that.